# Color a parent of an active dropdown list whilst its active using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, colors, html-lists

I'm making a website as a project for my class (using HTML, CSS, JavaScript mostly for regular expressions and jQuery for effects). The thing that I've been stuck on is the following:

I've been trying to color a li tag that that is active (it has a nested ul tag with 1 li element in it), say color it's top and bottom borders, color the parent li tag's text and remove the Font Awesome's plus and add a minus. So, by "default" the minus is hidden, the plus is active and is colored red, the text of parent li tag is white and it's top and bot borders are 1px solid and gray. When I click on it I want for it to drop down(which already does), remove the red plus, add the minus sign, color the li tag's text to red and make it's borders 2px solid red (top and bottom).

```
<div id="wrapperFAQ">
        <h2 id="h2FAQ">Frequently Asked Questions</h2>

        <ul id="listaPitanja">

            <li><i class="fas fa-plus activeTab"></i><i class="fas fa-minus"></i> Who are we?
                <ul>
                    <li>You can find more about us on our <a href="#">about us</a> page.</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-plus activeTab"></i><i class="fas fa-minus"></i> What products do we have?
                <ul>
                    <li>a</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-plus activeTab"></i><i class="fas fa-minus"></i> I have a hardware issue!
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-plus activeTab"></i><i class="fas fa-minus"></i> Where can I find your shop?

                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-plus activeTab"></i><i class="fas fa-minus"></i> Will you have "x" products in the future?
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </li>



        </ul>

        <p>Can't find your question on the list? 
        Send us an <a href="#">e-mail!</a></p>

    </div>
```

This was the HTML, this is the CSS:

```
#wrapperFAQ{
width: 80%;
padding:15px;
margin: 0px auto;
}

#h2FAQ{
font-size:4vw;
color:red;
float:left;
border-bottom:3px solid red;
border-left:5px solid red;
}

#listaPitanja{
float:left;
margin: 10px 20px;
padding: 5px 20px;

}
#listaPitanja li{
cursor:pointer;
border-top:1px solid gray;
border-bottom:1px solid gray;
padding: 15px;
}

.fa-minus::before,.fa-plus::before{
color:red;
}

#listaPitanja li ul,.fa-minus::before{
display:none;
}

#listaPitanja, #listapitanja li ul{
list-style:none;
width: 85%;
margin: 0px auto;
color:white;
margin: 10px 0px 0px 15px;
}

#listaPitanja li ul li{
border:none;

}

.activeTab{

display:block;
}

#wrapperFAQ p, #wrapperFAQ p a{
font-size:2vw;
color:gray;
font-weight:strong;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
width: 69%;
}

.aktivna{
border-top: 2px solid red !important;
color: red;

}
```

This is the jQuery:

```
$('#wrapperFAQ ul > li ul')
.click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
})
.filter(':not(:first)')
.hide();

$('#wrapperFAQ ul li').click(function(){
var selfClick = $(this).find('ul:first').is(':visible');
if(!selfClick) {
  $(this)
    .parent()
    .find('> li ul:visible')
    .slideToggle();
    $(this).addClass("aktivna");
}

$(this)
  .find('ul:first')
  .stop(true, true)
  .slideToggle()



});
```

Now, I did copy this exact code from a file I found online, most of it I understand, except the "stopPropagation" part, it's "e" argument (don't even know where it's coming from) and what its supposed to do, because when I remove it, nothing unwanted happens visually.

Moreover, you can see that I did add the class "aktivna" to the "active" menu (the class itself in CSS has only color:red; and border top and bottom set to 2px solid red with !important at the end). The problem is, how do I, using my existing code, implement the "inactive" way; to be more precise, if I open up another tab, I want the class on the active li tag to be removed and added to the other(opening one closes the last one). I did try fiddling with code; for example I tried moving to the parent of the $(this) after toggling it and removing the class, but the result I get is the active tab gets the class=""...This makes me rather confused, maybe I'm having a bit of misunderstanding on how my code works, I don't know, that's where I'm stuck on; color, borders, changing plus to minus and vice versa when switching from active to inactive etc. Sry for the long post

Answer (score 0):

Tip: use classes to help from getting confused about lists, list items and nested lists.

```js
$(".toggleItem").click(function() {
  // Remove active class from sibling toggleItems
  $(this)
    .parent()
    .find(".toggleItem")
    .removeClass("aktivna");

  // Check if we have clicked on a toggleItem that has an open toggleList
  var selfClick = $(this)
    .find(".toggleList")
    .is(":visible");

  if (!selfClick) {
    // Close the open toggleList
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .find(".toggleList:visible")
      .slideToggle();

    // Add active class to the clicked toggleItem
    $(this).addClass("aktivna");
  }

  // Open / close to the clicked toggleItem's toggleList
  $(this)
    .find(".toggleList")
    .stop(true, true)
    .slideToggle();
});
```

```css
#wrapperFAQ {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

#h2FAQ {
  font-size: 4vw;
  color: red;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  border-left: 5px solid red;
}

#listaPitanja {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

#listaPitanja li {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 15px;
}

.fa-minus::before,
.fa-plus::before {
  color: red;
}

#listaPitanja li ul,
.fa-minus::before {
  display: none;
}

#listaPitanja,
#listapitanja li ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  //color: white;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 15px;
}

#listaPitanja li ul li {
  border: none;
}

.activeTab {
  display: block;
}

#wrapperFAQ p,
#wrapperFAQ p a {
  font-size: 2vw;
  color: gray;
  font-weight: strong;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 69%;
}

.aktivna {
  border-top: 2px solid red !important;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapperFAQ">
  <ul id="listaPitanja">
    <li class="toggleItem"><i class="fas fa-plus activeTab"></i><i class="fas fa-minus"></i> Who are we?
      <ul class="toggleList">
        <li>You can find more about us on our <a href="#">about us</a> page.</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="toggleItem"><i class="fas fa-plus activeTab"></i><i class="fas fa-minus"></i> What products do we have?
      <ul class="toggleList">
        <li>a</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="toggleItem"><i class="fas fa-plus activeTab"></i><i class="fas fa-minus"></i> I have a hardware issue!
      <ul class="toggleList">
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="toggleItem"><i class="fas fa-plus activeTab"></i><i class="fas fa-minus"></i> Where can I find your shop?
      <ul class="toggleList">
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="toggleItem"><i class="fas fa-plus activeTab"></i><i class="fas fa-minus"></i> Will you have "x" products in the future?
      <ul class="toggleList">
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Can't find your question on the list? Send us an <a href="#">e-mail!</a></p>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/exErON)